# Hibernate not respecting MySQL auto_increment primary key field

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to learn how Hibernate works, and I am running into an almost unacceptable learning curve. I can't see how to get Hibernate to respect the auto_increment policy for my objects. Instead, it is overwriting entries in the database with existing IDs, beginning with 1.

I have a simple `Foo` object, backed by a MySQL table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Foo` (
  `fooId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fooId`),
)
```

I have confirmed that inserting multiple Foo objects by hand with SQL (`insert into Foo values();`) does the right thing.

My Java class has the ID specified using annotations like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="fooId")
private Integer id;
```

I then execute some test code that simply instantiates Foo objects and saves them to the database (using `session.save(obj)`). It seems that it uses its own primary key sequence, beginning with one, and does not look at the table's key policy. It overwrites whatever was there.

I have tried variations on the `@GeneratedValue` bit (using all possible strategies, leaving off the parenthetic clause). Somebody even suggested leaving off the `GeneratedValue` entirely. Nothing seems to work.

Am I leaving something out? What am I missing? Is Hibernate really this hard?

(If anybody has an alternative Java database persistence option, please suggest one. I am making prototypes, not long-lasting mondo-engineered projects.)

Comment: +1 for "almost unacceptable learning curve"

Comment: Ditto. Hibernate is not as smooth ride as EJB2 was, and lot of this has to do with devs refusing to support stuff than technical reasons.

Comment: Hibernate 5.x no longer uses IDENTITY when you specify GenerationType.AUTO. Instead it looks for hibernate_sequence table for the next id.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I believe you want `GenerationType.IDENTITY`.  MySql does not use a table or sequence for generating the Id value.

Comment: Hi Clint, and thanks for the reply. You are right. But that initially did not solve my problem, because I had a subtle, odious problem underlying everything. I'll post my answer under my original question.

Comment: Er, I changed my mind, I'll just answer it here.

I was using a hibernate.cfg.xml file off some dude's web site, and it had this:

    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

This made the system to re-create my table each time I ran my app. Commenting it out solved the problem.

Comment: Man i had the exact same problem with <property....>create</property>, thx for finding it ;p

Comment: If anyone still wondering whether to use GeneratedValue at all? I don't think annotating the ID as @GeneratedValue is a good idea as it takes a lot of hit on the performance. For details refer this [link](https://medium.com/@maqbool.ahmed.mca/spring-data-jpa-vs-data-jdbc-evaluation-b36d8834ead6)

Answer (score 5):

I wrote this in a comment under the accepted answer, but those aren't shown by default so I'll re-post it as an answer.

I was using a hibernate.cfg.xml file off some dude's web site, and it had this:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

This made the system to re-create my table each time I ran my app. Commenting it out solved the problem.

The other two answers about the various ways to create IDs are correct. My original problem's **symptom** seemed to do with ID generation, but the actual cause was misconfiguration.

Comment: You can also set that value to 'update' if you only want it to automatically match the database to your settings without dropping the data. The docs: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-misc-properties

Answer (score 2):

I think GenerationType.AUTO is right as is <id ...><generator class="native" /></id>

Picks an appropriate strategy for the particular database.

http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/ejb3-api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html

[http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/reference/en/html/mapping.html](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator)

Answer (score 1):

I use the following with auto_increment, works perfectly:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "db_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Long getDbId() {
    return this.dbId;
}

public void setDbId(Long dbId) {
    this.dbId = dbId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to have a look at:
http://hibernatepojoge.sourceforge.net/

It claims to create a fully working application (spring, hibernate, junit tests, etc) just by pointing it to a DB.