# how to implement auto increment in jpa

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jpa

I am about learning JPA, and I want to know how can we tel the entity manager that the primary key field is generated using the database auto increment to the table?
I am using Mysql 5.5 and Oracle Enterprise For Eclipse(OEFE) 
thanks for help

Comment: would have thought a simple search of the docs of your chosen JPA implementaton would give that; you don't say which one you're using ... EclipseLink?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to annotate MYSQL autoincrement field with JPA annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102449/how-to-annotate-mysql-autoincrement-field-with-jpa-annotations)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you have an identifier called `id` which needs to be auto incremented then:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

Comment: In some databases like **MySQL** you can use `@GeneratedValue` and `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` instead of `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` but it's not true with all databases. For example with **PostgreSQL** that won't apply and you should only use `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

Comment: This works only if you have not any column with an `@Id`