# ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to have many archives inside linf and some archives may have null linf. 
My essential hibernate annotatations are following:

```
@Entity
public class Linf {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Archive> getArchive() {
        return archives;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Archive {
    public Archive() {
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Linf getLinf() {
        return linf;
    }

    public void setLinf(Linf linf) {
        this.linf = linf;
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }


}
```

When I save Linf object via sess.saveOrUpdate(linfHbm), I get

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'archive_ID'
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at $Proxy21.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1260)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1210)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:399)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at org.kriyak.utils.ImportLinfs.main(ImportLinfs.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'archive_ID'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1039)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2683)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2144)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2444)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2362)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2347)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor28.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    ... 20 more
```

The last sql command that crashes process is:

insert into Linf_Archive (Linf_ID, archive_ID) values (?, ?)

Both fields in this table are not nullable.

Any idea why this can happen?

PS: I've isolated code that causes crash. Here is simple scenario, that produces the problem:

```
Session sess = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
sess.beginTransaction();
Archive a = new Archive();
Linf linf1 = new Linf();
Linf linf2 = new Linf();
linf1.setTitle("aa1");
linf2.setTitle("aa2");
linf1.getArchive().add(a);
linf2.getArchive().add(a);
sess.save(linf1);
sess.save(linf2);
sess.getTransaction().commit();
```

Note that archive has zero linf. May be this is illegal? But what if really want this scheme here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to annotate MYSQL autoincrement field with JPA annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102449/how-to-annotate-mysql-autoincrement-field-with-jpa-annotations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've found out, `@ManyToMany` relationship is exactly the one that should be used here. If signle object belongs to two different sets, then mentioned exception would happen in case `@OneToMany`.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using right `MySQLDialect`,

In addition, when adding `Archive` to `Linf`, are you `setting the parent object` before saving?

```
    public void add(Archive archive){
         if(this.archives == null){
              this.archives = new HashSet<Archive>();
         }
         archive.setLinf(this); //setting the parent
         this.archives.add(archive);
    }
```

Same when adding `MailSourceFile` to `Archive`? This is required to take care the foreign key population.

Comment: I want some Archives not to belong to any Linf, so I don't. Is it possible to make model to fit this requirement?

Comment: @stiv: Yeah that is fine. In that case save the `Archives` directly. I hope Linf mapping column would be Nullable in archives.

Comment: Additional saving new archive which has null linf doesn't help.

Comment: @stiv: What do you mean? It doesn't fit in your requirement or its giving some issue? If you are trying to save un-associated Archive through Linf then its fundamentally wrong.

Comment: I dont understand you too. If I can't find Archive of some sort, I make new Archive() and then save it. But I still get this exception. What can be wrong with my annotations?

Comment: @stiv: I mentioned two things in my answer. The relationship issue was another issue I noticed. You are not there yet. For your first problem, did you check your dialect?

Comment: Yes: cfg.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"); I use lastest mysql

Comment: @stiv Would you mind trying with `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect`?

Comment: @stiv Assuming there is no id as `1` in the database, can you please enable `sql trace` just to make sure if it's generating the right query in the backend?

Comment: I've added some more debug info.