# Auto key generation

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have a table:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ePrzychodnia`.`admins` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `firstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `lastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `personalId` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `personalId_UNIQUE` (`personalId` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `password_UNIQUE` (`password` ASC) )
```

and entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "admins")
@XmlRootElement
public class Admin implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 11)
    @Column(name = "personalId")
    private String personalId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
```

I used a  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

But if adding getting errors

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.mapLocal3xException(BaseContainer.java:2314)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2096)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy138.create(Unknown Source)
        at pl.ePrzychodnia.dao.EJB31_GeneratedAdminDaoIntfBean.create(Unknown Source)
        at pl.ePrzychodnia.facade.AdminFacade.create(AdminFacade.java:28)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy137.create(Unknown Source)
        at pl.ePrzychodnia.mb.AdminMB.createAdmin(AdminMB.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)
        at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:248)
        at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.checkExceptionClientTx(BaseContainer.java:5071)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4906)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
        ... 73 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'eprzychodnia.sequence' doesn't exist
Error Code: 1146
Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
        bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:840)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:906)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:592)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:535)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1717)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:253)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:216)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataModifyQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataModifyQuery.java:85)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:844)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:2831)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1516)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1498)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1463)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.QuerySequence.update(QuerySequence.java:340)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.QuerySequence.updateAndSelectSequence(QuerySequence.java:277)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.StandardSequence.getGeneratedVector(StandardSequence.java:71)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.DefaultSequence.getGeneratedVector(DefaultSequence.java:163)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.Sequence.getGeneratedVector(Sequence.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.SequencingManager$Preallocation_Transaction_NoAccessor_State.getNextValue(SequencingManager.java:468)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.SequencingManager.getNextValue(SequencingManager.java:1067)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.ClientSessionSequencing.getNextValue(ClientSessionSequencing.java:70)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.assignSequenceNumber(ObjectBuilder.java:349)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.assignSequenceNumber(ObjectBuilder.java:308)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.assignSequenceNumber(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:465)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4231)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:513)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4176)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:440)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:269)
        at pl.ePrzychodnia.dao.GenericDao.create(GenericDao.java:27)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
        ... 71 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'eprzychodnia.sequence' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
        at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:125)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:831)
        ... 124 more
```

Why? I must be doing something else? If I use generationType.AUTO need to add a sequence in the database or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't make id an auto increment column.  I'd recommend that you do so.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

You'll also want Hibernate to use an identity strategy.

[How to annotate MYSQL autoincrement field with JPA annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102449/how-to-annotate-mysql-autoincrement-field-with-jpa-annotations)

Comment: I changed `id` INT NOT NULL on `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, but still the same

Comment: Ok. I fix it. Delete the @NOTNULL annotation in the entity class and added work.