# Error with OpenJPA and processing a class

Tags: classnotfoundexception, openjpa, serializable, persistence.xml

This is the error shown:

```
exception

<openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: An error occurred while processing registered class "class no.avexis.fjellkam.Models.Cabin".
    org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.processRegisteredClasses(MetaDataRepository.java:1684)
    org.apache.openjpa.meta.ClassMetaData.getPCSubclasses(ClassMetaData.java:376)
    org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.findBaseClassMapping(MappingRepository.java:1539)
    org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.prepareMapping(MappingRepository.java:402)
    org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.preMapping(MetaDataRepository.java:769)
    org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolve(MetaDataRepository.java:658)
    org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaDataInternal(MetaDataRepository.java:418)
    org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaData(MetaDataRepository.java:389)
    org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ManagedClassSubclasser.configureMetaData(ManagedClassSubclasser.java:227)
    org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ManagedClassSubclasser.prepareUnenhancedClasses(ManagedClassSubclasser.java:182)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.loadPersistentTypes(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:312)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.initializeBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:236)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:212)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:155)
    org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:226)
    org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:153)
    org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:59)
    no.avexis.fjellkam.DAO.AdminDAO.getEvents(AdminDAO.java:161)
    no.avexis.fjellkam.Controllers.Common.ArticleServlet.doGet(ArticleServlet.java:33)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apache.openjpa.util.IntId]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Throwable.java:457)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1324)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1203)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    org.apache.openjpa.enhance.no$avexis$fjellkam$Models$Cabin$pcsubclass.pcNewObjectIdInstance(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCRegistry.newObjectId(PCRegistry.java:140)
    org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.processRegisteredClass(MetaDataRepository.java:1731)
    org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.processRegisteredClasses(MetaDataRepository.java:1681)
    org.apache.openjpa.meta.ClassMetaData.getPCSubclasses(ClassMetaData.java:376)
    org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.findBaseClassMapping(MappingRepository.java:1539)
    org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.prepareMapping(MappingRepository.java:402)
    org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.preMapping(MetaDataRepository.java:769)
    org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolve(MetaDataRepository.java:658)
    org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaDataInternal(MetaDataRepository.java:418)
    org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaData(MetaDataRepository.java:389)
    org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ManagedClassSubclasser.configureMetaData(ManagedClassSubclasser.java:227)
    org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ManagedClassSubclasser.prepareUnenhancedClasses(ManagedClassSubclasser.java:182)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.loadPersistentTypes(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:312)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.initializeBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:236)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:212)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:155)
    org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:226)
    org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:153)
    org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:59)
    no.avexis.fjellkam.DAO.AdminDAO.getEvents(AdminDAO.java:161)
    no.avexis.fjellkam.Controllers.Common.ArticleServlet.doGet(ArticleServlet.java:33)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1323)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1203)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    org.apache.openjpa.enhance.no$avexis$fjellkam$Models$Cabin$pcsubclass.pcNewObjectIdInstance(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCRegistry.newObjectId(PCRegistry.java:140)
    org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.processRegisteredClass(MetaDataRepository.java:1731)
    org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.processRegisteredClasses(MetaDataRepository.java:1681)
    org.apache.openjpa.meta.ClassMetaData.getPCSubclasses(ClassMetaData.java:376)
    org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.findBaseClassMapping(MappingRepository.java:1539)
    org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.prepareMapping(MappingRepository.java:402)
    org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.preMapping(MetaDataRepository.java:769)
    org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolve(MetaDataRepository.java:658)
    org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaDataInternal(MetaDataRepository.java:418)
    org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaData(MetaDataRepository.java:389)
    org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ManagedClassSubclasser.configureMetaData(ManagedClassSubclasser.java:227)
    org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ManagedClassSubclasser.prepareUnenhancedClasses(ManagedClassSubclasser.java:182)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.loadPersistentTypes(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:312)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.initializeBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:236)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:212)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:155)
    org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:226)
    org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:153)
    org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:59)
    no.avexis.fjellkam.DAO.AdminDAO.getEvents(AdminDAO.java:161)
    no.avexis.fjellkam.Controllers.Common.ArticleServlet.doGet(ArticleServlet.java:33)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Here is how I have class file looks like:

```
package no.avexis.fjellkam.Models;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CABIN")
public class Cabin implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9160490433220569097L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer cabinID;

    private String cabin;
    private String title;
    private String description;

    public Cabin() {
        this.cabin = "";
        this.title = "";
        this.description = "";
    }

    public Cabin(String cabin, String title, String description) {
        this.cabin = cabin;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getCabin() {
        return cabin;
    }

    public void setCabin(String cabin) {
        this.cabin = cabin;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getCabinID() {
        return cabinID;
    }

}
```

I keep getting this error for all my classes, and I either must be overlooking something, or I've done something very wrong.
It would seem as though there is an error while parsing the class, or locating the class?

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: This may related with your IDENTITY strategy, have a look in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102449/how-to-annotate-mysql-autoincrement-field-with-jpa-annotations

Comment: Thanks :) But stupid me had forgotten to add the jar files to the tomcat lib.