# Java JPA GenerationType.TABLE is not working

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish

I have a big Java EE project with many db Entities and the JPA constraint checking has given me a lot of headaches!

To begin with, I have many entities with many types of dependencies (OneToOne, OneToMany). The whole project is for automatic analysis and calculation of metrics about source code from OSS repositories. (se.uom.gr/seagle).

So for example there is an entity Project and an entity Project_Timeline that holds historical analysis info.

This is the Project entity Class

```
public class Project implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;


@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "name", unique = true)
private String name;

/**
 * A remote URL from where this project is cloned.
 * <p>
 */
@Size(max = 2048)
@Column(name = "remoteRepoPath", unique = true)
private String remoteRepoPath;

/**
 * The metrics that should be calculated on the next execution.
 * <p>
 */
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "registeredProjects")
private Collection<Metric> registeredMetrics;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "project", orphanRemoval = true)
private Collection<Version> versions;


@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "project")
private ProjectInfo projectInfo;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "project", orphanRemoval = true)
private Collection<ProjectTimeline> timeLines;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "project", orphanRemoval = true)
private Collection<ProjectMetric> projectMetrics;
```

And this is the Project_TimeLine entity class

```
public class ProjectTimeline implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "timestamp")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date timestamp;

@JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Project project;
```

If I understood correctly the JPA guidelines the proper creation for these entities is:

```
Project p = new Project();
project.setName("some-java-oss");
project.setURL("http:////bla bla bla");

ProjectTimeline pi = new ProjectTimeline();

pi.setProject(p);
p.setProjectTimeline(pi);

entityManager.persist(p);
entityManager.persist(pi);
```

So I only to this, and expect for the JPA to handle the primary keys and make a successful JOIN.

BUT

JPA and Glassfish keep giving me the following error:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -   2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): 
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception:    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:     Column 'id' cannot be null
Error Code: 1048
Call: INSERT INTO project_timeline (id, timestamp, action_id, project_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
  bind => [4 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(gr.uom.java.seagle.db.persistence.v2.ProjectTimeline[ id=null ])
 at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)

... 266 more

Caused by: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:     Column 'id' cannot be null

... 297 more
```

FULL error stack trace is here:

http://java.uom.gr/~chaikalis/documents/full_error_stacktrace.txt

Comment: Would using autoincrement fields and `GenerationType.IDENTITY` be an option? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102449/how-to-annotate-mysql-autoincrement-field-with-jpa-annotations

Comment: I have already explored the option of GenerationType.IDENTITY. 
Not working.

The manual creation is not an option for obvious reasons.

Comment: try @TableGenerator annotation
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/toplink-jpa-annotations-096251.html#TableGenerator

. Post full error stack trace.