# Spring Data JPA gets stuck at save method in test

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm having trouble to get my unit test working with the CrudRepository.save method. 
When I run my unit test it keeps running forever, not going past the save() method.

The last DEBUG message that appears in my console is:

```
16:20:35.293 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Done entity load
```

Now the weird part is that it is working if I execute one insert statement using the old JdbcTemplate, ONLY if the primary key is 1.
So for example; 

`INSERT INTO my_table (id, value) VALUES (1, 'Hello World')`

Will work, and the test will succeed
But this will not:
`INSERT INTO my_table (id, value) VALUES (2, 'Hello World')`

And the test keeps running forever

Already been looking for something like auto_increment not setup right, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Could you provide the exact code you are using for the JdbcTemplate inserts that is causing the running forever?

Comment: It's the other way around; by default my tests run forever and using the insert statement given in my question, it will make the test end.

Comment: Okay, so I've found out that the save() only works if it is updating. So when  ID x exists in the database, it will work, else it won't.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I found out that I needed to use a different value for the @GeneratedValue annotation for my auto incremented variable.

I used the first value from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4103347/5976604 and it worked afterwards.

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

I do think that it's annoying that Hibernate does not throw an exception or something when this occurs, but instead it gets stuck.