# Error: The given id must not be null for GeneratedValue in JPA

Tags: java, rest, jpa, spring-boot, spring-rest

My object:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name="uid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

  //more code
 }
```

When I `POST` `user` `JSON` without `uid`, I am getting error as *the given id must not be null*. Which should not be the case while `uid` should be generated by the database. Please point what am I missing.

JSON:

```json
{
"email": "john@mail.com",
"name": "John Doe",
"phone": "98-765-4445"
}
```

Error:

```json
{
"timestamp": 1501058952038,
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException",
"message": "The given id must not be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!",
"path": "/api/user/"
}
```

Comment: can you try --> @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE), this uses sequence table id assignment

Comment: No, it does not work.

Comment: @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) will work, Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102449/how-to-annotate-mysql-autoincrement-field-with-jpa-annotations

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was my bad, I was calling `foo(user.getId())` before saving the `User` object into the database.
Takeaways from this: `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` is the correct code and generates identical ids while saving to database<sup>1</sup>. And `Long` is not a problem. Thanks.

[1]: I am saving the object into the database by, something like: `userRepository.save(user)`.

Comment: It is always a good practice to post the correct code once you find the solution so that new learners who cannot understand jargons (like persisting in this case) can grasp it quickly.

Comment: @Rahul thanks, I did it long time ago. I edited as much as possible. Hope it is better now.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong WHETHER you do `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` or `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)` in this particular problem. Any strategy works. ALL you have make sure is `@PathVariable` is used or not when you are passing `id`.

Answer (score 0):

To generate string uuid's for primary keys (as I assume you are trying to do) you can try the following code:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private String id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue encountered with `findById()` method while I was missing `@PathVariable(value="id")` ID id in `getIdSpecificResult()` method. This was a minor missing piece on my code. Reasons could be any though.