# Issue with resetting auto increment from default to big number

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-jdbc

I have a MySQL table naming Invoice for a Inventory Monitoring site, invoice_number is bigint(19) AUTO_INCREMENT field.

Currently AUTO_INCREMENT value is 1.

Client want it to start the invoice_number from 50000.
With the following script reset the ALTER TABLE INVOICES AUTO_INCREMENT = 50000;
When I wrote an Insert Script to insert data in SQLDBX, it is putting the invoice_number from 50000.
But when i am trying to do insert a record using the application(web application), the invoice_number value is starting from 1.
We are making use of Spring-JDBC template to insert data into mysql database.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. There is something else going on, like different tables, or databases, or the web app is creating its own increments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the Hibernate HBM mapping for Invoice. The generator class for Invoice Number is Increment.

```
<id name="invoiceNumber" column="INVOICE_NUMBER">
   <generator class="increment"/>
</id>
```

By modifying the generator class to identity it worked.

```
<id name="invoiceNumber" column="INVOICE_NUMBER">
    <generator class="identity"/>
</id>
```

For more detailed information, please check
[Hibernate problems with Auto Increment ID MYSQL 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838520/hibernate-problems-with-auto-increment-id-mysql-5)
Also check this
[Hibernate not respecting MySQL auto_increment primary key field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582526/hibernate-not-respecting-mysql-auto-increment-primary-key-field?rq=1)